# A shell script to import a mysql datase - ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, linux, database, shell, lamp

I want to import/restore a dump of mysql database. To do that i have found a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
# A shell script to restore a large SQL dump using root login.
# Usage: ./restore_dump.sh dump.sql app_devdb


(( $# != 2 )) && { echo "Usage: $0 dump.sql database_name"; exit 1; }
[ ! -f $1 ] && { echo "$1 not found1"; exit 1; }

RESULT=`mysql -u root -p --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$2'"`
if [ "$RESULT" != $2 ]; then
    echo "Database '$2' does not exist; creating it...";
    mysql -u root -p -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $2;"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && { echo "Unknown error in attempting to create database '$2'"; exit 1; }
fi

(
  echo "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;"
  echo "SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;"
  echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;"
  cat $1
  echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"
  echo "SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;"
  echo "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;"
  echo "COMMIT;"
) | mysql -o -u root -p "$2"
```

the above shell script supposed to restore the db dump if it exists other wise it will create a the db and then execute the sql file. For some reson i cant get it to work. once i execute it i am getting the bellow error

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

But i can access my sql through phpmyadmin and there i can execute the the dump by importing it. i have also tried the simple version of this script

```
mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD DATABASE < DATABASE.sql
```

there also i am getting the same error. cant figure out why. also i could not find a folder called mysqld in `/var/run`

i am using lamp server in kubuntu 16.04
mysql version 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

**UPDATE**

I have installed XAMPP server. I did not install every thing manually one by one

Comment: Execute the command please to ensure that your mySQL is runing:
mysql status

Comment: i am getting the same error when i am running that also. But i can access my sql through php my admin and all my php applications are working fine

Comment: Are you sure, phomyadmin is hosted on the same server?
Try also: mysql -v

Comment: yeah i am using my localhost so i am sure. and the result of mysql -v is  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Are you sure it's not Mariadb running rather than mysql. Run "netstat -antp | grep 3306" and verify what's running on port 3306.

Comment: that gives me this out put
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2971/mysqld

Comment: Specify the host name of mysql server in the command, it may help you.